# How to keep my balcony door partially open?

Tags: doors, bolts, fastener

The door on my balcony has a system that allows me to keep it open at any angle I desire. Unfortunately, this has broken: my door closes when it's windy. I want to fix it.

The system works with a wing nut that I screw on a bolt. But, the wing nut breaks the thread of the bolt: I can turn the wing nut indefinitely without it going up. Replacing the wing nut or the bolt only solves the problem temporarily.

- A friend suggested I use a wing nut with a longer thread, but I cannot find such a thing.
- Using a bolt with a higher diameter is not possible, since it has to fit within the slit. The bolt has a diameter of 6mm, the slit is 6.5mm wide.
- Are there bolts/nuts of a stronger/harder material? I'm using a galvanized nut. I don't know what material the bolt is.

[image: Door patially open lock system]

Comment: The track/holder might be what is causing damage to the threads.  Every time it slides it will tend grind the threads down a bit, like a file.

Comment: i would add nylon washers on both sides of the track clamp and grease the track well to reduce thread wear and holding capability.

Comment: Has this happened more than once? I find it hard to believe that the bolt would strip without a whole lot of use, and it doesn't make sense that the bar would strip the threads inside the nut.

Comment: Does the door also open when it's windy, or only close?

Comment: @isherwood When it happened the first time, I added some metal washers so the nut screws a bit further down the bolt. Then after a while I had the same problem. Then I replaced the bolt. Again, the same problem after a while. Then I replaced the nut and it seemed to work. But now with an eye nut I have more confidence that it will keep working.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was:

- Add nylon washers (@dandavis)
- Grease the track (@dandavis)
- Replace the bolt
- Use an eye nut instead of a wing nut. It has a longer thread (at least for eye nuts and wing nuts I found) and is also easier on the hands.

[image: Eye nut]